# Ant jar Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath

I am running a jar with a particular argument for eg: `testscript run` then this testscript exists in different directories so I run the jar of that script using the java jar command of ant something like this:

```
<java jar="testscript-jar.jar">
<arg value="run"/>
</java>
```

By doing that I get error `Could not find or load main class`.

This command works fine for the first 2-3 instances but start showing error for the rest of the directories.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `jar` attribute points to the correct path of the Jar file relative to the Ant's project base dir. See this quote from the [`java` task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html):

> The parameter of the jar attribute is of type `File`; that is, the parameter is resolved to an absolute file relative to the base directory of the project, *not* the directory in which the Java task is run. If you need to locate a JAR file relative to the directory the task will be run in, you need to explicitly create the full path to the JAR file.

Comment: so the jar param and location param is the same? or jar is just the name, location is the exact location?
Also I need to do everything through ant file

Comment: @fscore Forget `location`. Make sure `jar` is set to the correct path relative to the base dir.

Comment: Well I tried what you said and I get "Error: unable to access jar file" for some files it works but for some it gives that error "error: unable to access jar file"